# Fast principal component analysis

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I'd like to speed up a principal value value analysis.
The data contains a large set of vectors with a large dimension. Both are in the range of 1000. I want to obtain the loadings matrix for further calculations.
The "Eigenvectors" part takes most of the computation time.

```
lMat = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1000}, {j, 2000}]; 
mwVec = Mean[lMat]; 
lVerMat = (# - mwVec) & /@ lMat (* translation to the mean *); 
covarMat = Covariance[lVerMat]; 
loadMat = Eigenvectors[covarMat] (* loadings matrix *); //AbsoluteTiming 
lHKMat = lVerMat.Transpose[loadMat];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the built-in function [PrincipalComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PrincipalComponents.html)?

Comment: The loadings matrix and the mean values should be fixed for the transformation of additional data. PrincipalComponents yields just the result and not the tranformation rules.